# how to read files and its subdirectories files using perl

Tags: perl, recursion

in Perl i need to read file from a parent directory to it's last file it any sub directory is there i need to read those files too!so I've tried something like this with the help of `recursive function` but it gives **infinite loop** so can anybody help me!
code;

```
sub fileProcess{
(my $file_name)=@_;
print "$file_name it is file\n";
}
sub main{
    (my $dir)=@_;
    chdir $dir; 
    my $tmp=`pwd`;
    my @tmp =<*>;
    chomp(@tmp);    
    foreach my $item(@tmp){
        chomp($item);
        if(-d $item){
            dirProcess("$tmp/$item");
        }else{
            fileProcess($item);
        }
    } 
}
sub dirProcess{

    (my $file_name)=@_;

    print ">>the corresponding dir is $file_name<<";    
    main($file_name);

}
my $home="../../Desktop";
chdir $home;
my $path=`pwd`;
main($home);
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the [wheel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule)?

Comment: no i just want to write manual func!

Comment: @ThiyaguATR use File::Find

Comment: i want to achieve this without using Perl modules!

Comment: @ThiyaguATR But it's a core module, you don't have to pull it from cpan.

Comment: Look it up on the Perl documentation: [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html).  It is a core module, so it is available everywhere.  Why would you want to reinvent the wheel, complete with dubious square corners?

Comment: The main issue in your logic is the use of `pwd`. `pwd` will always return the directory you were in when you ran the script.

Comment: @imran: No, it doesn't. It would be pretty useless if it did. Using `pwd` in backticks creates a child of the `perl` process, and returns the present working directory of that process, which has been inherited from its parent *at the point the child was created*.

Comment: @Borodin you're right.

Comment: @ThiyaguATR: Perl modules ARE a part of Perl.  Don't waste your time writing, debugging and testing code that has already been written, debugged and tested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sub that will search recursively :

```
sub find_files {
    my ($dir) = @_;
    my (@files, @dirs) = ();
    my (@allfiles, @alldirs) = ();

    opendir my $dir_handle, $dir or die $!;
    while( defined( my $ent = readdir $dir_handle ) ) {
        next if $ent =~ /^\.\.?$/;

        if( -f "$dir/$ent" ) {
            push @files, "$dir/$ent";
        } elsif( -d "$dir/$ent" ) {
            push @dirs, "$dir/$ent";
        }
    }
    close $dir_handle;

    push @allfiles, @{ process_files($_) } for @files;
    push @alldirs, @{ find_files($_) } for @dirs;

    return \@alldirs;
}
```

Comment: That should be `while( defined( my $end = readdir $dir_handle ) ){...}` prior to [Perl 5.12](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html).

Comment: Hi kjprice!. i am trying to use your method however i am getting deep recursion warning.

Comment: Hi kjprice you forgot to put the `next if ($e =~ /^..?$/);` clause before searching for directories. Thats is why the deep recursion message

Comment: Hi kjprice just need to clarify .. will i be able to return lets say `return @dirs` so that i can use this subroutine in other subroutines?Such as returning all the compiled list of `@dirs` to other subroutine where i can open all the directories and look for certain files.

whenever i return `return @dirs` to be used in other subs i only get the child folder but not the folders in child folders and so on

Comment: @DeepakTivari Also, as I commented on that question. Why would you re-implement this, when `File::Find` is already a core module.

Comment: @kjprice i am a beginner in perl in my polytechnic and my project involves the understanding of recursion so i have no choice but to learn fundamentals.

Comment: @DeepakTivari In that case, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your code isn't working is that, when `dirProcess` it calls `main` again which does `chdir` to a different directory. That means the rest of the files in the `@tmp` array aren't found.

To fix it I have just added a `chdir $dir` after the call to `dirProcess`. In addition I have

- Added `use strict` and `use warnings`. Yyou must *always* put these at the top of your program.
- Removed all calls to `pwd` which were unnecessary. You know what you present working directory is because you've just set it!
- Removed unnecessary `chomp` calls. The information from `glob` never has trailing newlines. The one string that *did* need chomping is `$tmp` but you didn't do it!

It's still not a very nice piece of code, but it works!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub fileProcess {
    (my $file_name) = @_;
    print "$file_name it is file\n";
}

sub main {

    (my $dir) = @_;

    chdir $dir;
    my @tmp = <*>;

    foreach my $item (@tmp) {
        if (-d $item) {
            dirProcess("$dir/$item");
            chdir $dir;
        }
        else {
            fileProcess($item);
        }
    }
}

sub dirProcess {

    (my $file_name) = @_;

    print ">>the corresponding dir is $file_name<<\n";
    main($file_name);
}

my $home = "../../Desktop";

main($home);
```